# How to use XCopy in a build script instead of copy in Windows

Tags: xml, build, command-prompt, nant, xcopy

Earlier to deploy my dot-net project into my remote server I was using **copy** command in a nant build configuration file. The command is shown below.

```
<target name="Deploy">
    <copy  todir="${path.to.the.directory}" overwrite="true">
        <fileset basedir="${Bin.Path}">
            <include name="*.*" />          
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Now as my project grew I got two new folders inside my $[bin.path] folder and now I cannot use **copy** command to copy my executable to the output folder.

What can I do?

After searching I found out I can use **XCopy**. But I am not getting how to integrate that into my build script similar to the one shown above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wonder why you came to a conclusion that you can't use `<copy>` task.

If you need to include the subfolders into the copy set, change your NAnt script to this:

```
<target name="Deploy">
    <copy  todir="${path.to.the.directory}" overwrite="true">
        <fileset basedir="${Bin.Path}">
            <include name="**\*.*" />          
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

If you don't want to keep the folder structure in the target directory, you can use `flatten` attribute of `<copy>` task:

```
<target name="Deploy">
    <copy  todir="${path.to.the.directory}" overwrite="true" flatten="true">
        <fileset basedir="${Bin.Path}">
            <include name="**\*.*" />          
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Hope this helps.